# Android - Populating listview using array of linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am trying to populate my ListView using an ArrayList of LinearLayout (because of reasons). Each of the LinearLayout have their own controls (Button, TextView, etc.) as child view.

I tried to do it just now, but I got an error.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot 
be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
```

Here is my adapter's code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    view = arrayNestedContent.get(position).getView(context);

    return view;
}
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

For listviews you use an Adapter and in the getView method you would link to your custom linearlayout with an inflater. You inflate the layout in getView then return the new layout at the end.

Something like this in your adapter's getView method:

```
View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_name);
Button button = row.findViewById(R.id.buttonID);
TextView someView = row.findViewById(R.id.tvID);              someView.setText(arrayNestedContent.get(position).text);
button.setOnClick.....
return row;
```